# Pi 3 model B+ won't boot

Tags: boot, pi-3b+

I was using this specific Pi for over a month now without any issues. Today, out of the blue, the screen started flickering. I decided to shut it down. When I replugged it, the green led wasn't flashing and the red led was always on. I tried to boot with multiple SD cards (including freshly flashed ones) but It never booted. In all my efforts the red led was always on. Any thoughts?

Comment: may be a bad power supply

Comment: I don't think it is a power issue since I tested it with the official psu as well as usb to my computer

Comment: `usb to my computer` will never supply enough power. Regardless, I had an issue like this once - was a dirty connection on the SD slot - in my case it I just cleaned the connectors and all worked again

Answer (score 1):

First, I see in your comment that you tested the official PSU (after the accident), but what about during the accident? With the new RPi 3B+ the power supply is very important. Use only 2.5A or higher and never use PSU that charge tablets/phones/batteries (usually they decrease their voltage while load increases).

The red light according to eLinux.org means: `PWR LED is also a power good indicator that goes off when power drops below 4.65V`. The green should be  `flashing during SD card activity`

Your problem sounds like a hardware failure, may be overheating. Did you measure the temperature when the problem occurred? Raspbian can show current temp on the task menu. Did you use a heatsink, good aluminum case, or fan?

While the following will not fix your problem, you can find if your RPi boots at all. You will need a USB to TTL (RS232) serial cable like  Adafruit 954 or FTDI TTL-232R-RPi. I would go with FTDI, but the price is very steep. When you connect the cable to your Mac/PC you will be able to see some more info while RPi boots [image: Image is from Adafruit site] [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/enabling-serial-console) and eLinux.org have tutorials how to use the cable.