# What is the correct way to connect serial console on RPi4 Model B?

Tags: pi-4, serial-console

My `config.txt` has:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1
```

at the end and my cmdline.txt has:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200
```

And here's how I've connected it:

[image]

I followed this based on some other examples on this site. But when I connect my picocom exits saying `FATAL: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory` and I see these error on my syslog:

```
kernel: usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
kernel: usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
kernel: usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
kernel: usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
kernel: usb usb1-port3: attempt power cycle
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
kernel: usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
kernel: usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
kernel: usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

(I think, I may have fried my serial cable).

What is the correct way to open the serial console from a Linux desktop?

Comment: Why have you disabled Bluetooth? Why are you you using obsolete cmdline settings?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your issue is that your computer won't recognize a USB to UART dongle (code 71 means "no response packet received within the prescribed bus turn-around time", meaning the device is not replying to USB commands). This is not really a Pi-4 related issue.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've tried this with 3 other cables, they all report the same and go extremely hot. Could you please suggest the right way to connect it?

Comment: @Milliways  I might've read [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) incorrectly then. Hence the question. Sorry, if I'm wrong. What is the correct cmdline?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First a complete picture with "official" colored wires.
[image]
Thanks to [fiery](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/85265/fiery) for providing this [picture to connect an USB to TTL serial adapter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/82992/79866).

As shown in the pinout you have mixed up TXD (pin 8) and RXD (pin 10). Maybe it is the reason why your adapter get hot?

[image: pinout]

Then to `/boot/config.txt` I have only added

```
enable_uart=1
```

No need to disable bluetooth. My `/boot/cmdline.txt` looks like this:

```
console=serial0,115200 root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

If you want to have also a normal terminal attached then you must add `console=tty1` to the line so it should similar to this:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet
```

This is the default *cmdline.txt* on *Raspbian Buster Lite* but this will not show all boot messages on the serial console. Of course don't touch your PARTUUID. I use the nice tiny program **tio** (terminal IO) that is exactly made for serial terminal connections and works out of the box. After installing it with `sudo apt install tio` I call it with:

```
lxdesktop ~$ tio /dev/ttyUSB0
tio /dev/ttyUSB0
[tio 21:06:05] tio v1.32
[tio 21:06:05] Press ctrl-t q to quit
[tio 21:06:05] Connected

raspberrypi login:
```

Comment: I don't think he's got the pins mixed up TXD on the USB serial cable goes to RXD on the pi and vice versa.

Comment: @justinjt If you see it from that side you may be right...

Comment: @justinjt If the pins were swapped, I'd at least see some garbage. But here, I don't see anything. I'll try your method right now and see how far I go.

Comment: @justinjt `kernel: [174467.510879] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32` This happened. I swapped them to the order as show in your image and I saw a `?` on screen and syslog reported this. I call as `picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -r -l`.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer I said I _don't_ think you have the pins swapped. The way you have it in the original picture is correct. `RPI TXD -> usbserial RXD`, `usbserial TXD -> RPI RXD`

Comment: @justinjt I connected a logic analyser. After the initial bits (possibly just bumps) nothing else appears on both channels when I boot.

Comment: @justinjt I have no idea what went wrong, but my logic analyser is now picking up the signals and I can actually see the contents appearing. Thanks Ingo.

Comment: Good to hear. These are the pitfalls when dealing with real hardware. You can have everything set up correctly, but one slightly loos wire will make everything go wrong and can be very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: With the new Debian 12 images, the config is as described but 1) the serial login session indeed works 2) the serial console messages are not there. I know we can't get the kernel start messages this way, but I expected I would see Systemd bootstrap the board. Nothing until login session appears

Answer (score 1):

This "correct" way is to run `sudo raspi-config` Select **Interfacing Options / Serial** then specify you want a Serial console.

This is explained in [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

There is nothing wrong with the link you referenced (which should be edited into your Question - along with any other detail) - **if** you actually followed it. Despite your comment you must have followed some obsolete instructions to come up with your `cmdline.txt`.

Both my tutorial and the Foundation tutorial contain additional detail (which was needed when the Pi3 was first released, but the appropriate settings are now done in `raspi-config`).

> Other Issues

Your `cmdline.txt` is obsolete (experienced users make a backup copy of system files BEFORE modifying them). You should change the `root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02` to match your SD Card - the appropriate PARTUUID can be found by running

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

Which will contain a line like:-

```
PARTUUID=f6650ff2-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

---

It is difficult to see WHAT you are doing to produce the error:-

> FATAL: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory and I see these error on my syslog:

This has **NOTHING** to do with serial console!
Indeed there will **NOT** be a `/dev/ttyUSB0` unless you have a serial device plugged in to the Pi.

Comment: There's a tiny problem though. I have a buildroot based build and it doesn't have `raspi-config` in it. I was building this for a router. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually the appropriate PARTUUID can be found more reliably by running `blkid`.