# Can RaspberryPi 4 output display on USB 3 port?

Tags: display, usb3

I have multi-computer setup with couple of Windows, a RaspberryPi 2, and a Mac. I use a Dell D6000 docking station which can connect computers on USB C and USB B 3. Unfortunately for my Pi2, I always have to connect over WiFi and use VNC. However when I play with its network interfaces, I have to connect it to one of my monitors on HDMI, and it may sound simple but folks with multiple computers on a standard sized desk can understand the pain.

I plan to upgrade to Pi4 and I understand that its USB Type C CANNOT be used for display as it is solely for power input, the question is, can its USB 3 port be used as video out?

Comment: I'm no pi expert, but I'm pretty sure the answer is no. you definitely cant plug n play from any usb for video(as far as I know, but i've only connected keyboard and mouse), but maybe after doing something in the terminal you could do it.

Comment: Displaylink compatible suppliers have some USB 3 monitors that have Linux support but never tried them on a Pi... e.g. https://www.mimomonitors.com/pages/using-mimo-with-raspberry-pi but this needs a specific monitor, powered hub and kernel version.  You can run VNC on a virtual console that is not connected to the display.

Comment: For playing with the network interfaces you can [use the serial debug console](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108781/79866).