# UART and AP Question

Tags: pi-3, gpio, uart

I have a wifi access point that I need to connect to via UART/SERIAL as the console rj45 is broken.

I have a USB UART cable on the way but it’s going to take a while to get here.

Is there any way I can interface the access point with the GPIO pins on the RPi and somehow get a console connection to the AP? I’ve got jumper cables already so hoping there is a way to do it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see any real relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I am wanting to use the Pi to connect to the AP via the GPIO pins. It’s heavily relevant on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: "the console rj45 is broken" there is no such thing!

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The console port has broken pins so a rollover console cable won’t connect properly...

Comment: `It’s heavily relevant on the Raspberry Pi?` ... why are you asking that question? ... anyway, no, it is not ... you could just as easily use a PC

Comment: you are asking about establishing a console port connection to an unknown AP

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase a cheap USB to TTL serial adapter and connect it to the pins 6, 8, and 10. With a serial terminal program you can use the debug console that is exactly the same console as used with `ssh`. For details you can look at [What is the correct way to connect serial console on RPi4 Model B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108781/79866).

Answer (score 1):

There are several UARTs on the Raspberry Pi and at least 2 are connected to GPIO pins.

So yes, you can connect one of the UARTs on the GPIO pins to the wifi access point. Just make sure that the wifi access point uses 3.3V levels and not 5V levels or you also need a level changer.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to go into more detail about how I would achieve this?

Comment: RTFM which pins are uarts and connect them.