# Restore WiFi settings on headless Pi after a failed attempt at setting up a hotspot

Tags: wifi

I just followed the instructions given [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) for setting up a wireless hotspot to connect to my Pi with.

However, I think I must have done something wrong.

As I am using a headless Pi, and have no screen or keyboard or ethernet, this means I can't access it anymore. I also can't edit the ext4 portion of the SD card from Windows.

Is there any way reset the WiFi behaviour so that it tries to connect to my router again, and so give me access to my Pi?

*Update:* In the end I realised I had a SD card with USB adapter lying around. I installed a new OS on the spare SD, and fixed my other card from there. I think the question is still valid. Since you can set the wpa_supplicant.conf file, and enable ssh by putting files on the boot partition, I would have thought you might be able to do other things.

Comment: Restore from your backup!

Answer (score 3):

If you can do nothing, no keyboard/screen, no ethernet connection, no access to the root partition, then there is of course no possibility to modify and repair the installation. You can only reflash the Raspberry Pi from the image.

Or you decide to purchase a piece of hardware to get access to the running RasPi. For this situations the Raspberry Pi has a serial (debug) console but you need a USB to TTL serial adapter to connect to it. The good news: it costs less than 10 €. How to use it you can look at [What is the correct way to connect serial console on RPi4 Model B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108781/79866):