# How to access Serial Console on Rtaspberry Pi CM4?

Tags: pi-4, compute-module-4

I have a RPi CM4 Lite and IO Board. I am trying to access serial console using USB to TTL Rs232 Module Converter Serial Cable Adapter [Serial cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08HPSFFTT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

I have connected Black wire to pin 6(Ground), White to pin 8(TxD) and Green to pin 10(RxD), Red +5V is not connected to any pin of IO Board. I could see log messages during boot. I am using MobaXterm tool on my laptop to access serial console.

I have also set `enable_uart=1` in config.txt

But I am not able to type anything from console. Like my keyboard input is not being passed to console. Also tried by connecting keyboard to IO board, but still same situation. It fails to respond to the keyboard.

I observed that if I connect HDMI display instead of serial cable then keyboard inputs are passed. So, I assume it's something to do with serial cable connection.

Can someone please let me know if the connection is proper and what is wrong here?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this thread https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/what-is-the-correct-way-to-connect-serial-console-on-rpi4-model-b

Comment: Hi @D3mon, thanks for the link. I have exact same connection and also i could see boot messages. Only thing is I cannot type/input anythinfg from serial console. It fails to respond to the keyboard.