# Operating systems with serial OOTB

Tags: headless, image, terminal

Which Raspberry Pi operating system images have a serial console enabled out of the box? This is needed for a client to debug why they are not getting HDMI out of their Raspberry Pi 4. The client does not have the technical know-how to change the boot partition's `config.txt` offline, so needs something that will have a serial console enabled with no modifications.

Comment: How do you expect someone who can't edit one file to attach a 3.3V serial terminal?

Comment: I can guide him over skype to do that. Not to install Linux.

Comment: Wait, is the boot partition FAT32 in raspbian?

Comment: Raspbian comes with boot as FAT32 and the remaining partitions exFAT.  You could edit the config.txt file on any PC or Mac.  Maybe create a small program they run?

Comment: Root and boot are two different partitions... And so far as I remember, config.txt is in boot.

Comment: @Milliways sorry spent all day using exFAT disks with a Pi (blush) - you are correct it’s ext4

Answer (score 2):

All Raspbian images have a serial console prepared to just enable it, but it isn't enabled out of the box. You have to add this line to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
enable_uart=1
```

The file `config.txt` is stored on the boot partition of Raspbian that is formated as **fat** so you can modify it on nearly all other computer with different operating systems. Attach the flashed SD Card with a card reader to another computer and add that line to *config.txt*. Of course you can do it also on the booted SD Card in the RasPi. Then [attach the USB adapter cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/82992/79866) and [use the serial console](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108781/79866).