# Raspberry Pi 3b - Undervoltage problem after using same power supply and cable

Tags: pi-3b+

I have been using RPi 3b for several months with a set of power supply and cable. I recently upgraded raspbian to Bullseye. That was also fine. I added a camera today and then on RPi is not booting. I connected a monitor with HDMI and it shows undervoltage error with a yellow flash. Except OS and Camera, nothing has changed.

Even after disconnecting camera, issue now persists. The device is not booting which means I cannot do anything over wifi and ssh.

Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pi 3 model B+ won't boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82946/pi-3-model-b-wont-boot)

Comment: You need to work through similar questions until you find an answer which works for you.

Comment: What does "upgraded raspbian to Bullseye" mean? If it shows under voltage it means your power supply or cable is inadequate. It is doubtful that there is any relationship between the two.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the voltage and current specifications of the power supply and the specifications of the camera. Adding a camera (in case the power supply was already working at its limits) or a mistake while doing so might have damaged the power supply. Can you measure the voltage?