# Raspberry won't boot, how to check/fix SD card?

Tags: boot-issues, osmc

I know there is a ton of topics "My raspberry won't boot" but I need to create a new one, sorry :) I simply didn't find the solution to my problem anywhere.

My Raspberry 3 with OSMC suddenly stopped working a few days ago - no internet (ethernet port was also "dead") and TV just showed "no signal"., but on the other hand LEDs were blinking both (it's a good sign, right? :) ). So I tried second SD card with a fresh image of OSMC and Raspberry booted without any problem. So I assume there must be a problem with SD card but after connecting it to my laptop it was mounted without any issue and fsck found just a few errors. But even after fixing those errors raspberry still behaves the same way.

Of course, I can simply reinstall the OSMC and it will (probably) work fine but I'm too lazy to configure it again. So I'll be happy for any help or hint. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote you can read and repair the old SD Card attached to your laptop. So just take an image of it and flash it to the new SD Card you have verified that it is working.

If this doesn't help then you can try to debug why the RasPi does not boot correctly. You will find some steps at [Can't boot from SD-card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/111978/79866). Or - depending on the effort - you start again from scratch and swear to take a backup of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to restore the image from the old SD card to the new one (which worked with fresh OSMC image) by this guide https://beebom.com/how-clone-raspberry-pi-sd-card-windows-linux-macos/ and the same situation like before - LEDs are blinking but that's all, everything else is dead. Any other idea? The image itself must be somehow corrupted, but how to check it? Fsck doesn't show anything, SD card is working normally on the laptop.

Comment: @user1928543 I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these errors can not be fixed. These types of problems most of times happens because of crashed applications or scripts. I have seen many problems like this. Even if I use it with great care, some problems always come back. I suggest you take a backup and get inside your rootfs with another linux PC or use some software in windows to get there. Recover everything and re install the image.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm too lazy to configure it again. So I'll be happy for any help or hint."

**Make a backup**.

Experienced users don't usually attempt recovery (it is too much work, and unreliable) - we just restore from a backup if the image becomes corrupt.

Comment: Thanks Milliways, but what file/folder should I backup and upload back to the newly imaged SD card? So I will have a "fresh" installation of OSMC but with old settings...