# New Raspberry Pi 4B refusing to boot

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

My new Raspberry Pi arrived today, I had a micro SD card ready to go. I connected the HDMI0 and power cable after ensuring the SD card was inserted correctly. Sadly, even after waiting a few minutes, nothing was still showing. I had a mouse and keyboard connected which also showed no signs of life. I tried reimaging the SD card several times, with different images on it, even some directly from the Raspberry Pi website, but still no luck.

When power is connected, both the power and act LED light up, but the act LED does not blink at all to show it is reading anything, or even to show any errors. This is really frustrating, especially as I have spent a good bit on the Pi as they are currently being scalped due to chip shortages. Any help is appreciated!

The micro SD card being used is a 128gb SanDisk Extreme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 4B wont start, 0 long blinks 1 short blink](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116701/raspberry-pi-4b-wont-start-0-long-blinks-1-short-blink)

Comment: @joan The act light does not blink at all, not even once, so I don't believe it does sadly

Comment: The point is you need to work through the boot sticky.

Comment: If the green ACT led does nothing either there is no card inserted, the card is improperly formatted, or the Pi is broken.